# imagePickerControllerDidCancel can not be called

Tags: uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I use uiimagepickercontroller to take picture and set overlayview, there is a button for canceling uiimagepickercontroller

```
UIButton *btnCancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnCancel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 20, 20);
[btnCancel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelshoot) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[overlay addSubview:btnCancel];

- (void)cancelshoot
{
  NSLog(@"cancel");
  [self.imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
  NSLog(@"can this be called?");
  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

imagePickerControllerDidCancel can not be called after click the cancel button, only prints log 'cancel', how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The button you created is connected to the `cancelshoot` method, so exactly the right thing is happening. Dismissing the picker at that point is up to you.

The `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:` delegate method is for when the user clicks the *picker's built-in Cancel button*. Cocoa has no idea that your button is a cancel button - the fact that you called it "Cancel" in its title is not magical in some way.

Note that on iPad, where the picker is a popover, there is no Cancel button and so `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:` is *never* called.

Comment: thanks, and is there a way to fix this on iPhone except picker's built-in Cancel button?

Comment: What's to fix? You've added a button and it's working. What's the problem now?

Comment: I mean can I use the button that I added to call the `imagePickerControllerDidCancel `?

Comment: You must not call `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:`. It is a delegate message; it is Cocoa's job to call it for you.

Answer (score 0):

implement pickerDelegate use picker to dismiss it's self

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        //
    }];
}
```